# Python script only works after saving and closing MXD then re-opening ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-location, arcgis-10.8, error-000229

I'm very new to using Python scripts in ArcMap (10.8). I've got a script that exports a suite of maps for our clients, but it always gives me an error

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open Counties & Quads\County Failed
> to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).

at a certain portion of the script. However, if I save the MXD, close out of ArcMap, re-opon the MXD and run the script, it works all the way through.

Any idea why that would happen?

Not sure if you need the whole script, but this is the portion it always gets held up on:

*UPDATED with more script:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
client = "CLIENT"
lyr1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Map Data",df)[0]
lyr2 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Data",df)[0]
lyr3 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Contours & Drainages",df)[0]
lyr4 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Loomis Model",df)[0]
lyr5 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Counties & Quads",df)[0]
lyr6 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Quarter Quad Lookup",df)[0]
lyr7 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Basemap Group",df)[0]
lyr8 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"Basemap",df)[0]
lyr9 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"*Soils",df)[0]
...
#COUNTIES PDF
lyr1.visible = False
lyr5.visible = True
lyr8.visible = False
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(r"Counties & Quads\County","INTERSECT","Property Boundary")
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(r"Counties & Quads\County","CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,r"C:\Users\sporterfield\Desktop\\"+client+"_County.pdf")
#ZOOM BACK TO PROPERTY BOUNDARY
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(r"Property Boundary","INTERSECT","Property Boundary")
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(r"Property Boundary","CLEAR_SELECTION")
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"T:\Topoquads\mapdata\Texas_Parks_and_Wildlife_Department\Texas Ecological Systems\Phases.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,addLayer)
lyr5.visible = False
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
del mxd, df
```

Comment: There may be something in the rest of your script which deletes or otherwise damages the layer.

Comment: What is `r"Counties & Quads\County"`, a layer or feature class?

Comment: @BERA it's a layer

Comment: I think you need to provide more of the script. There is something happening before this select by that is creating an issue.  Please provide the where the script is interacting with or creating that layer.

Comment: @JTaylor I updated the original post with more script